# Android: How to make UI thread to wait till AsycTask completes

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-asynctask

Currently, I'm executing a heavy task inside AsycTask which uploads images. When I do it via AsycTask, the application closes and no error message appear in the logcat.

```
    private class SendIncidentTask extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Double... params) {
                lat1 = params[0];
                log1 = params[1];
                SendingIncident sincident  = new SendingIncident();
                sincident.sendInciWithoutAttachment(lat1, log1);
                sincident.submitWithAttachment(lat1, log1);
                return null;
            }

   }
```

I think issues occur when the UI thread and AsycTask execute in parallel. How can I make the UI thread wait until the AsycTask finishes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do not just execute that task in ui? If only thing you want is to make a job and close ui...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use onPostExecute method to load UI.This is automaically called after doInBackground is completed

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss the real problem, and doing what you want will cause ANR. But if you want the UI thread to wait, just execute it as a method of the activity, and not as AsyncTask.

Comment: Wot you are saying is true but if I left it in UI thread, OS thinks app hanged and prompts to forceclose the app. Anyway Now I moved the stuff dat should be executed after the Asyc to onPostExecute. Anyway wot you are saying makes a lo of sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you make the UI thread to wait until the end of the AsyncTask, the application will also think (and for a good reason) that the UI thread hangs...